# Im running the code of Point Feature Histogram given in PCL documentation, and this is the output I'm getting

Tags: point-cloud-library

This is the output I'm getting after the PFH code. What do the zeroes mean?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial you are using/ what your source-code looks like?  With this little information, it is very hard to even begin to try to answer this question.